# How to change rendered value through controller

Tags: visualforce

```
  <apex:pageBlockSection id="RecurrsiveDetails" rendered="{!checkBoxDetailsMultiPay}">
                    <apex:selectRadio  id="Frequency" layout="pageDirection" value="{!frequency}" >
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Daily" itemLabel="Daily" ></apex:selectOption>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Weekly" itemLabel="Weekly"></apex:selectOption>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Monthly" itemLabel="Monthly"></apex:selectOption>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Yearly" itemLabel="Yearly"></apex:selectOption>
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!checkFrequency}" reRender="RecurrsiveDetails"/>
                    </apex:selectRadio>
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="true" id="ViewForDaily">
                <input type="radio" checked="checked"/> Every<input type="number"/>Days
                        <br/>
                 <input type="radio" />Every WeekDay
                    </apex:outputPanel>
```

in this code I want that when the daily radio button is checked only then will this outpanel show that is change its render to true, else false. How can i achieve it inside the controller ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the actionSupport so that it says `reRender="RecurrsiveDetails,ViewForDaily"`

Then change the outputPanel to say
`rendered="{!IF( AND(!ISBLANK(frequency), frequency=='Daily'), true, false)}"`

Comment: <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!frequency=='Daily'}" id="ViewForDaily">  It says wrong attribute value when I put this in rendered

Comment: I modified the format a bit and added a null-check. Does that work better for you?

Answer (score 0):

small change to the above answer--

In the action support --> reRender="RecurrsiveDetails,ViewForDaily"

and then change the outputPanel to --> rendered ="{!if(frequency='Daily', true, false)}"